# How to hide CSS by default and show on button press

Tags: plugins, jquery, widgets, css

I have the Elementor Pro page builder plugin installed and I want to setup a expanding column so when a button is pressed it expands more Elementor sections.

I'm pretty certain this can be done with jQuery but can't get it to work properly.

I got the button to work using this code

```
jQuery( document ).on( 'click',  '#MY_BTN', function( event ) {
   event.preventDefault();
   // Show/Hide the widget
   jQuery( '#MY_WIDGET' ).toggle();
});
```

but I couldn't get the section to hide by default, how do I achieve this?

Many thanks

Thomas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can actually hide it on page load using **`jQuery ready()`** method:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#MY_WIDGET').hide();
});
```

Comment: Hello Magefms, I have tried using that code in my custom javascript plugin but no luck.

Comment: is `#MY_WIDGET` the id of the section?

Comment: Hi magefms, yes but once clicking on the button it disapears.

Comment: can you show me the section code? you can actually set the default visibility by an in-line CSS style

Comment: Hi magefms, of course i can, but ill have to provide a link to an image screenshot of the code which I hope will be suitable. [link](https://gyazo.com/fe9643ebb70a90df2b3ce387a331fffc)

Comment: The code kind off works now, but now when clicking the button the code hides the text box instead of me clicking the button to display the content underneath. I hope that makes sense?

Comment: can you paste your code in your question? and what is the main issue now? because I was assuming the code above in your question is already working for hide and show and what you want is to just set it to hide by default